# embedding datacamp light in wordpress blog post

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, reactjs

I am trying to embed datacamp light exercise in WordPress 5.0.4 blog post, but it seems not working.

I have tried with this code in the wordpress text tab:

```r
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>


<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="r" data-height="100" id="r-exercise">
  <code data-type="pre-exercise-code"># no pec</code>
  <code data-type="sample-code">
    # Calculate 3 + 4
    3 + 4

    # Calculate 6 + 12
  </code>
  <code data-type="solution">
    # Calculate 3 + 4
    3 + 4

    # Calculate 6 + 12
    6 + 12
  </code>
  <code data-type="sct">
    test_output_contains(&quot;18&quot;, incorrect_msg = &quot;Make sure to add `6 + 12` on a new line. Do not start the line with a `#`, otherwise your R code is not executed!&quot;)
    success_msg(&quot;Awesome! See how the console shows the result of the R code you submitted? Now that you&#39;re familiar with the interface, let&#39;s get down to R business!&quot;)
  </code>
</div>
```

The result is that the session seems broken or not connecting, and the code is not shown. Please see my attempt at the bottom of this page: http://www.insular.it/2019/01/incrociare-due-tabelle-dplyrinner_join-vs-merge/

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use word press. There are 3.5MB too much of junk scripts

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks. What do you mean by "do not use word press"? I have a wordpress website so I don't know if I have a choice (I don't have good skills in handling websites as well! Just knowledge of R really)... how could I avoid this problem?

Comment: You can use my soon-to-be-released Command Blocks website app if you do not want to learn HTML/CSS/JS but want a 100000000000000x faster to develop, more secure, more feature-rich, less buggy, and more performant website. I shall notify you in a few weeks when it is ready.

Comment: please do I am really curious and thanks for sharing your knowledge